# Mac Automator -- mount a network volume

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mount, rsync, shell-script, automator

I am writing an Automator "script" that `rsync`s media on my 10.6.3 MacBook Pro to my Ubuntu 10.10 HTPC. I can make Automator run my shell script for `rsync` commands, but I can't make Automator mount the three volumes on the HTPC (folders for music, videos, and pictures).

I automatically mount these volumes when I login, but sometimes the HTPC volumes get unmounted, so I'd like to remount by default.

Is there a way to mount the volumes in Automator? I am open to shell scripting, too. Thanks!

Comment: This would be a great question for http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why are there so many stackexchanges now? Does it help with ad revenue? Doesn't tagging work? I added it there, too. Should I delete this one? I am a relative newbie to stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find out the name of your drive, i store it in a shell variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
backupVolume=`diskutil list | awk '/ Backup / {print $6}'`
```

"Backup" is the name of my drive. Something like "disk2s1" will be stored in this variable. This part of the shell script mounts the drive:

```
if [ ! -z "$backupVolume" ]
then
  diskutil mount $backupVolume
fi
```

To automatically eject a drive you can use this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject "Backup"'
```

I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this tonight. Does it matter that the two computers connect via a wifi network?